# The fireEvent.click() from @testing-library/angular not working for 'ion-button' component but works for normal button

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework, angular-testing-library, jest-dom

I am developing an application with Ionic Angular. While I am testing with @testing-library/angular, the test is not working for **ion-button** but works for normal **button** field. What could be the problem?

**fireEvent.click()** event is not working for the code below (ionic angular):

```html
<ion-button data-testid="button-submit" class="login-submit-btt" type="submit" size="large">Test</ion-button>
```

And **fireEvent.click()** event works with the following code:

```html
<button data-testid="button-submit" class="login-submit-btt" type="submit" size="large">Test</button>
```

The code I am using for testing is below:

```html
import {
  LoginFormData,
  LoginFormPresentationComponent,
} from './login-form.component';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/angular';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

test('Login button should not be disabled', async () => {
  const loginData: LoginFormData = {
    login: 'dev',
    password: 'dev',
    stayLoggedIn: false,
  };
  await render(LoginFormPresentationComponent, {
    componentProperties: {
      loginData: loginData,
      commitChanges: {
        // because the output is an `EventEmitter` we must mock `emit`
        // the component uses `output.emit` to interact with the parent component
        emit: submitAction,
      } as any,
    },
    imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, IonicModule], 
  });

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('button-submit'));
  expect(submitAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(loginData);
});
```

And the Version I am using:

```html
"@angular/cli": "~14.1.1",
 .....
"@testing-library/angular": "12.1.2",
"@testing-library/dom": "^8.17.1",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"@ionic/angular": "6.2.5",
"@ionic/core": "6.2.5",
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ionic works, but it might be that they're not listening on the native click event.
Try using user-event instead of fireEvent.
This represents a "real" user, and doesn't only fire a click event, but fires more events.

https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with both "fireEvent" and "userEvent" , but results are same. :(